# Compiler specific memory initialization

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, memory, gcc

Is there a way to ensure the order of static object initialization for certain objects for the entire program. I have memory allocators that I would like to be allocated as the first things in a program, as they will be used else where throughout the program and I want to use these allocators to allocate all later memory.

I understand this is probably compiler specific as I don't believe the C++ standard allows this. The two compilers I am interested in doing this for is gcc and VS2010's compiler. If there is a way, could someone explain how?

**EDIT**

I do not want "construct on first use" because the allocators will be allocating a large block of memory that I want initialized at the start of the program.

Comment: You mean "to ensure the order of static object initialization" or what?

Comment: You might want to rewrite your question. Because it doesn't make much sense the way it is

Comment: @Grizzly: What does not make sense about it?

Comment: Mostly this: "Is there a way to ensure certain memory will be allocated first in a program?". What exactly do you mean by this. Do you mean the order in which static objects are initialized? What memory do you mean and when exactly should it be initialized?

Comment: @Grizzly: I did say "I would like to ensure the order of static object initialization for certain objects" and for "when exactly should it be initialized" I said "allocated first".

Comment: @Grizzly: I updated the question again to hopefully give more clarity.

Comment: I strongly suggest you rethink your aversion against the "construct on first use" since it will do exactly what you want: One of your statically initialized objects will win and initialize it "on first use" before it and all your other statically initialized objects are initialized.

Comment: Or maybe you should consider allocating your allocator's memory statically.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can somewhat affect the order of initialization  by using compiler specific directives. MSVC has a pragma

```
#pragma init_seg({ compiler | lib | user | "section-name" [, func-name]} )
```

that can somewhat set the priority for a specific module. See this reference for [init_seg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx).

The gcc compiler has a similar/related attribute syntax for setting the *relative* priority of a specific initialization. It looks  like this

```
Some_Class  A  __attribute__ ((init_priority (2000)));
Some_Class  B  __attribute__ ((init_priority (543)));
```

and is explained on this page on [init_priority](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html).

Comment: Very interesting. Could you provide an example of how to do Some_Class for MSVC?

Comment: @Bo Persson: Would you be able to show an example of Some_Class for MSVC? After reading the documentation I do not see how something similar to Some_Class A is possible (though I do believe it is possible, it is what the documentation says, however, I can not seem to be able to achieve it).

Comment: You can't get exactly the same functionality for MSVC. You can add `#pragma init_seg(lib)` to the file initializing an object of `Some_Class` to get it initialized before user code. You cannot get an exact priority for each individual object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're referring to the static initialisation order fiasco, whereby your program has a chance of invoking undefined behaviour when a static variable is initialised based upon the state of another static variable (Which may or may not have had its constructor called at the time) .

The workaround to this problem is the *construct on first use* idiom, described in the C++ FAQ here:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15

Comment: I looked into this previously, however, I do not want "construct on first use" because the allocators will be allocating a large block of memory that I want initialized at the start of the program.

Comment: @chadb: Maybe you should describe in more detail what you are doing. Because from your question I would assume construct on first use to be perfectly fine (note that first use can be inside the construction of a static object).

Comment: So, you would have your memory allocation trigger by the first initializer to try to use it.

Comment: @ams: That would require a check for every memory allocation. That is definitely not ideal.

Comment: No, not ideal, but you were going to check the return result anyway, right? How much more expensive is a simple NULL-pointer check. You *could* have a special function you only use in static initializers, and another in normal code so that you don't have the overhead once it's guaranteed initialized (I'd recommend an assert, even then, which you'd compile out when you did a release-mode build).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to control static initialization, which will only cause you hours or more of ridiculous debugging time in the future, allocate your pool of memory at the start of `main`. Then you still get your pre-allocated memory without all the pitfalls of static init.

Comment: That's a bit late for all those static initializers that run before main and rely on the memory in question.

Comment: harvard arch. processors might need the static initialization to store data on program memory, usually read only flash memory on AVR uC.
as a read only memory you can not runtime allocate or initialize.