# Using init_seg to call an initialization function

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying to ensure a function will get called first by the program to ensure the initizilation of critical objects. However, I am confused as to how `init_seg` is suppose to be getting used/called.

For example, from the documentation at msdn it would seem as if the following would be the first to be called.

```
#pragma init_seg( ".CRT$XCC" )

static void InitializeStuff()
{
    printf("InitializeStuff\n");
}
```

However, that does not seem to be the case as that function will just plainly not get called automatically (unless I call it explicitly, of course).

How can I use init_set to ensure a function is called before the rest of my other executing code?

Comment: You want it to be called before `main()`? That is all you want?

Comment: I want to ensure it is the first thing called for my application. I was suggested this earlier today from the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10198675/compiler-specific-memory-initialization with Bo Persson's answer.

Comment: I think you need to use the fourth (?) version of [`init_seg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx) that uses the function name: `#pragma init_seg( ".CRT$XCU", "InitializeStuff" )`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood it right you place all global variables that you want to be initialized first in the same file as the `#pragma init_seg`

Example:

```
#pragma init_seg( ".CRT$XCB" )

class A
{
    A()
    {
        printf("first!\n");
    }
};

static A first;
```

And make sure you dont place any other globals in that file than the ones you want to initialized first.

Comment: Your example shows the use of a class, however, I was hoping to do this with a function as I mentioned in my post. Is there a particular reason why you demonstrated a class? Does it have to be a class? Is it not possible to do with a function? If it is not, why not?

Comment: No its not, the pragma directive only sorts the creation order of static/global objects, since their order is otherwise unsorted/unknown. If you want to call a function first in your program why not just call it first?

Comment: If you really want to use the init_seg directive wich i would advice you not to, you can make a class and run all initalisation code in its constructor( replace the "printf("first!\n");" with your code)...

Comment: `warning C4075: initializers put in unrecognized initialization area`
Does seem right? (in vs2015)