# How to name sections/groups for three C++ objects when using init_seg?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, static-order-fiasco, visual-c++-runtime

I'm using `init_seg` to control the creation of three C++ class objects. Each object is in a different source file/translation unit. Debugging shows the objects are being created as expected during CRT initialization.

The objects are being initialized in alphabetical order of their source file. I'd like to change it because its not quite right. I visited MSDN's page on [`init_seg`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx), and it states the use is:

```
#pragma init_seg({ compiler | lib | user | "section-name" [, func-name]} )
```

It appears the use of `lib` and `section-name` are mutually exclusive, so its not clear to me how to use `init_seg(lib)` and provide a section/group name to get the alphabetical ordering right.

When I attempt to use an alphabetized string to control order:

```
#pragma init_seg(lib, "01")
```

It results in a warning, which I am guessing means things are not going to  work as expected:

```
warning C4081: expected ')'; found ','
```

When I try to insert directly into the CRT startup code directly using `".CRT$XCB"`, `".CRT$001"`, and `".CRT$XCB001"` (and other variations of utilizing alphabetization):

```
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCB")
```

It results in another warning, which I am guessing means things are not going to work as expected:

```
warning C4075: initializers put in unrecognized initialization area
```

I found one question on Stack Overflow about it, but the [answer was a guess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10205800/608639) and it does not cover multiple translation units. I also found an archive of [KB104248](https://web.archive.org/web/20120110121800/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104248) on the Wayback Machine, but its not much help either because it only shows the use of `compiler`, `lib` and `user`.

So my question is, how do I utilize `init_seg` to control the precise order of creation of my three objects in three different source files?

Comment: Have you looked at the example code in MSDN?  I think I can make a reasonable guess, based on that code, how you would do what you're asking for, but it sounds like you're looking for an answer based on personal experience?

Comment: Thanks Harry. Which example code are you referring? I looked at the code provided with [`init_priority`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx) page, but I have to admit I'm not making the connection between `mine$a` and `.mine$z`, the allocations, and replacing the startup code. The standard CRT startup seems adequate. I only need to insert my three objects in a particular order.

Comment: If I'm reading the docs correctly, when you use named sections, the CRT will not initialize or destroy the static objects for you, you must explicitly call the constructors and destructors.  The up-side of that is it allows you to control the order.  That example code appears to be using knowledge of the compiler internals to call the constructors for whatever objects are in the named sections, but I think that's an unnecessary complication in your case - you know what the objects are, so you can construct and destroy them by name.

Comment: If you then place a static object inside `init_seg(lib)` the constructor and destructor for that object *will* be run automatically, and from there you can call the constructors and destructors for the various named sections in the desired order.

Comment: Oops, actually it sounds like the compiler *will* destroy the static objects for you, unless you specify `func-name` in the call to `init_seg`.  That allows you to control the destruction, but appears to be optional.  You probably don't need it.  Just call the constructors on startup and let the CRT call the destructors as usual.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I found through testing on XP and VS2002/VS2003, Vista and VS2005/VS2008, Windows 7 and VS2008/VS2010, Windows 8 and VS2010/VS2012/VS2013, and Windows 10 using VS2015. `#pragma_init(<name>)` has been available since VC++ 1.0 days. MS does not publish too much information about it, but we know its documented from [VC++1.0 (archived KB104248)](https://web.archive.org/web/20081009023141/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104248) through [VS2017](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7977wcck.aspx).

1. `#pragma init_seg(lib)` is almost perfect. However, the object files are alphabetized in VS2008 and earlier, so the init order is `a-b-c` (unwanted) rather than `c-b-a` (desired). Its OK on VS2010 and above. What's not obvious is the order is laid out precisely as `c-b-a` in the `vcproj` files.
2. `#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCB-0NN")` seemed to work. Our `std::strings` `STRING_A` and `STRING_B` were created early (and the objects were in the right order), but `STRING_B` caused a crash at suhutdown. The address was `0x0000000d`, and it appears the `std::string` (and its vtable) were destroyed too early.
3. `#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU-0NN")`  worked as expected during startup and shutdown. If I parsed what I read correctly, then the `U` in group name `XCU` indicates user defined objects. It means our objects were created somewhere in-between what `#pragma init_seg(lib)` and `#pragma init_seg(user)` provides.

So here is how to initialize an object C, then an object B, then an object A from source files `a.cpp`, `b.cpp` and `c.cpp`.

***Source file `a.cpp`***:

```
class A
{
    ...
};

#pragma warning(disable: 4075)
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU-030")
A a;    // created 3rd
#pragma warning(default: 4075)
```

***Source file `b.cpp`***:

```
class B
{
    ...
};

#pragma warning(disable: 4075)
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU-020")
const B b;    // created 2nd
#pragma warning(default: 4075)
```

***Source file `c.cpp`***:

```
#pragma warning(disable: 4075)
#pragma init_seg(".CRT$XCU-010")
const std::string c;    // created 1st
const std::string d;    // created 1st
#pragma warning(default: 4075)
```

---

Our use case was to create three read only objects and avoid the problems with C++'s [static initialization order fiasco](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) and Microsoft's [thread local storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx).

The technique avoids missing C++ dynamic initializers in C++03. It also side steps Microsoft's inability to provide C++11's [Dynamic Initialization and Destruction with Concurrency](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2660.htm) (or more correctly, Microsoft's failure to provide the core language feature for 10 years).

Here's a reference to the issue on [Thread Local Storage (TLS)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yh4a9k1.aspx) on MSDN:

> On Windows operating systems before Windows Vista, __declspec( thread ) has some limitations. If a DLL declares any data or object as __declspec( thread ), it can cause a protection fault if dynamically loaded. After the DLL is loaded with LoadLibrary, it causes system failure whenever the code references the __declspec( thread ) data. Because the global variable space for a thread is allocated at run time, the size of this space is based on a calculation of the requirements of the application plus the requirements of all the DLLs that are statically linked. When you use LoadLibrary, you cannot extend this space to allow for the thread local variables declared with __declspec( thread ). Use the TLS APIs, such as TlsAlloc, in your DLL to allocate TLS if the DLL might be loaded with LoadLibrary.

Its also worth mentioning that there does ***not*** appear to be a limit on the number of characters in the section or group name. The archived [KB 104248](https://web.archive.org/web/20081009023141/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104248) uses the name *`"user_defined_segment_name"`* with 26 characters.

Comment: The specified section name becomes a section in the executable. The final name is 8 characters or less. Anything longer is truncated, and the extra characters, or anything after a $, is used for relative ordering within the specified section.

Comment: I think [CRT Initialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb918180.aspx) is relevant, it describes the .CRT section.  I'm not sure whether this constitutes a promise to maintain the same architecture in future versions of the CRT, but at least you're not in completely undocumented territory. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure what the relevance of thread local storage is here.  Do you mean that being able to control the order of initialization means that you don't need to use DLLs?

Comment: @Harry - We produce a library. Others may use it to create a DLL. We have to engineer for the use case.

Comment: OK, but how does using `init_seg` help?  The restriction on `__declspec(thread)` will still apply, as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `#pragma section` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50bewfwa.aspx) to specify the attributes of the section if you use a custom section name

```
#pragma section("foo",long,read,write)
#pragma init_seg("foo")
```

You can ensure that custom segments from multiple files are ordered by adding a suffix after a dollar sign.

```
// tu1.cpp
#pragma section("foo$1",long,read,write)
#pragma init_seg("foo$1")

// tu2.cpp
#pragma section("foo$2",long,read,write)
#pragma init_seg("foo$2")
```

The data from tu1.cpp will now be before that from tu2.cpp

You can order things relative to the C runtime library by adding a suffix to the CRT segments

```
// tu1.cpp
#pragma section(".CRT$XCU1",long,read,write)
#pragma init_seg("foo$1")

// tu2.cpp
#pragma section(".CRT$XCU2",long,read,write)
#pragma init_seg("foo$2")
```

TU1 is now before TU2, and grouped with other data

Comment: Thanks Anthony. Its not clear to me how this solves the problem. Does `#pragma init_seg("foo")` place the object after Microsoft's C++ library initialization in `crt0.dat` but before user object creation? Also, how do we do that x3 for three C++ objects in three different source files?

Comment: I've extended my answer to address this